# IOS Parse include key query

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to print the name of a category using Parse in iOS and Objectve-C. Thanks for looking. Let me know if you have any questions.

CategoryInBudget Table

category(pointer)
amount(number)
user(pointer)

Category Table

name(string)

Here is my code:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"CategoryInBudget"];
    [query whereKey:@"user" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
    [query includeKey:@"Category"];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        for (PFObject *object in objects) {
           NSLog(@"%@", object[@"Category"][@"name"];
        }
    }];
```

Comment: What happens when you run this code?

Comment: Is Category with an upper case C correct?  By convention it would be a small c

Comment: You are the best. Thanks. I changed [query includeKey:@"category"]; and NSLog(@"%@", object[@"category"][@"name"];